# PHP: Remove a line from a string

Tags: php, string, line

I have an svg file where I want to remove points if the x and y value are the same.
For example: `<path d='M2.38922,-128.262 2.38922,-128.262' stroke='#ffff33' />`

This is my attempt so far:

```
$file = file_get_contents("../maps/test.svg");
foreach(preg_split("/(\r?\n)/", $file) as $line)
{
    if(strpos($line, ' d=') !== false)
    {
        $space = explode(" ",$line);
        $space = str_replace("d='M","",$space);
        $space = str_replace("'","",$space);

        echo "|$space[1]| => ";
        echo "|$space[2]|";
        if($space[1] == $space[2])
        {
            echo "    X delete duplicate<br>";
            unset($line);                 //<-- does not work!
        }
        else
            echo "    O keep<br>";
    }
}
```

Here is the page running the code: http://176.9.218.179/livemap/livemap.php
It properly finds them, but doesn't remove the lines.
How would I unset these lines from the string? (the "delete dup" is for debugging purposes, not to be actually printed either)

PS: How can this code be written to be as efficient as possible? (might be run several hundred times)

Comment: You are unseting simple variable, not doing any changes to file content itself. In each foreach iteration $line is created with COPY of appropriate data. No point to unset. You would want to collect good data and then overwrite (or create new) file with it.

Comment: @Endijs Which variable should i be unsetting? Or should I copy the entire file into a new variable with the omitted data?

Comment: Added code. check and tell if that solves problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$file = file_get_contents("../maps/test.svg");
$good = array();
foreach(preg_split("/(\r?\n)/", $file) as $line)
{
    if(strpos($line, ' d=') !== false)
    {
        $space = explode(" ",$line);
        $space = str_replace("d='M","",$space);
        $space = str_replace("'","",$space);

        echo "|$space[1]| => ";
        echo "|$space[2]|";
        if($space[1] != $space[2])
        {
            $good[] = $line;
        }
    }
}
// $good now holds good lines, feel free to write them into file or output
```

Comment: How it can be one character, if you set it in foreach and then do not overwrite anymore? In which moment does it become one character?